# $window load for ng-views

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

`.directive('resizer', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {`

```
        angular.element($window).on('load resize', function () {

          var sectionHeight = angular.element(document.querySelector('#aboutContentSection'))[0].offsetHeight;


          if (sectionHeight) {
              if (elem[0].scrollHeight + sectionHeight < $window.innerHeight) {
                elem.addClass('footerSetBottom')
              } else if (elem[0].scrollHeight + elem[0].offsetTop >= $window.innerHeight) {
                elem.removeClass('footerSetBottom')
              }
          }

        });


    }
}
```

}])

However the problem is as I'm using ng-view's when I go to a new page, the `load` in the above is not being called.

I'm assuming this is because the page has technically loaded and its just new `ng-view` being used.

So my question - what construct should I use to get into that code without having to refresh the entire page or resize the window?

Thanks.

Comment: ngView has onload event. From there it's easy to trigger window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

Crate a `.run()` function for your module and listen the event `$routeChangeSuccess` on the `$rootScope`

like this:

```
angular
  .module('YourApp')
  .run(runFn);

runFn.$inject = ['$rootScope','$window'];

function runFn($rootScope, $window){

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
    angular.element($window).on('load resize', function () {
     //... Some Logic
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using it for a custom directive - so not sure how to implement your solution - I've updated my question above with complete code.

Comment: In what element you attach this directive?

Comment: In `<div class="footer" resizer>`

Comment: Also in the above it goes into the `$routeChangeSuccess` however from there it doesn't proceed into the on `load resize` section of code.

Comment: Are you tried putting the footer outer the ng-view?